# how can i auto-register strings with wpml in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, translation

i am trying to auto register string in wordpress, but for some reason it doesn't work

it works when i call in the code of the theme:

```
esc_html_e('mytext','mythemename');
```

and then do

```
WPML->theme and plugins localization->strings in the theme->scan the theme for strings
```

then mytext appears in strings list for translation

but if i try instead to enable:

```
 wpml->string translation->auto register strings for translation->auto-register strings always->apply
```

and in the code run, f.ex.:

```
$myvar='mytext';
esc_html_e($myvar,'mythemename');
```

then, of course, i go to wp page where string appears, but nothing happens, string doesn't get added to theme strings list

does anybody know if i am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it started adding the strings when instead of esc_html_e i wrote:

```
icl_register_string('mythemename','myvariable',$myvar);
echo icl_t('mythemename','myvariable',$myvar );
```

i'm sure there is more elegant solution but since this one works it'll do for now.